# Set access in for GIT projects from Gerrit Code Review only to specific group

Tags: git, gerrit

I have been controlling the access for all projects with LDAP groups, and access was inherited from ALL-Projects option.

But now i have a requirement where i need to create one projects and the LDAP group to which am giving the access should be able to see contents of only this project and not other existing projects.

So in this case shall I not inherit the access from ALL-Projects or is there any other access tip which will abandon these users from viewing my other existing projects on same GIT server.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the All-Projects inherit and use the "**BLOCK and ALLOW rules in the same access section**" feature to block the original access and grant the access to the new group.

See more info [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#__block_and_allow_rules_in_the_same_access_section).